# Why $d_2=0$ implies homotopy to constant maps?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm trying to formally prove the following claim:

> $d_2$ is $0$ ... so the maps $\Delta_{\alpha\beta}$ are homotopic to constant maps. (Hatcher's *Algebraic Toplogy*, [example 2.36](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1671399/understanding-example-2-36-in-hatchers-algebraic-topology-calculating-homology?rq=1))

where:

- $\Delta_{\alpha\beta} : \partial D^n_\alpha \to S^{n-1}_\beta$ is the attaching map of $e^n_\alpha$ followed by the quotient map $X^{n-1} \to S^{n-1}_\beta$ collapsing the complement of $e^{n-1}_\beta$ in $X^{n-1}$ to a point.
- $d_2$ is the boundary map of the CW complex with formula:

$$ d_n(e^n_\alpha) = \sum_\beta deg(\Delta_{\alpha\beta})e^{n-1}_\beta$$

(all from Hatcher - p. 141).

So, for example, in the torus we would have two such $\Delta$ maps - one per $1$-cell in the $1$-skeleton, using the standard CW construction of the torus from one $0$-cell, two $1$-cells and one $2$-cell.

So I want to show that $f_0=\Delta_{\alpha\beta}$ is homotopic to some constant function $f_1$, but what is $f_1$? It cannot be $d_2$ because the domain and codomain are not the relevant $S^1$'s. I thought of somehow using the formula for $d_2$ to extract $\Delta_{\alpha\beta}$ as a function of the other $\Delta$s, but I don't see how, specifically because it is wrapped up in $deg(\Delta_{\alpha\beta})$.

What am I missing? Would also appreciate understanding intuitively why this homotopy holds. I'm currently not seeing it at all.

([related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1671399/understanding-example-2-36-in-hatchers-algebraic-topology-calculating-homology?rq=1) that doesn't [explicitly enough that I can identify it] answer the question)

Comment: There is a lot of contact missing here. What is $d_2?$ What is $\Delta_{\alpha\beta}?$

Comment: Apologies - added now (wrongly assumed the reference to the example would be sufficient).

Comment: Should it be obvious when $e^n_\alpha$ is?

Comment: You're misrepresenting the statement from Hatcher. He says that $d_2=0$ because the maps $\Delta_{ab}$ are homotopic to constant maps.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri (a) Why do I need that? $d_2=0$ because it is of the form $a+b+c+...-a-b-c-...=0$. In light of this (which is stated with the commutators before the quoted ",so..."), the added statement regarding the homotopy seems redundant. (b) Is the homotopy induced by the fact that: $deg (f) = deg (g) \implies f \cong g$ (by Hopf) somehow? (using $f=\Delta_{\alpha\beta}$ but what is $g$?)

Comment: Is $g=0$ ($g:S^1 \to S^1$) using parameterization by an angle $\theta$ so the range is $[0,2\pi]$ and then $g$ sends everything to the $0$ angle? (and now we can indeed use Hopf?), or, directly write the homotopy: $F(x,t)=tf(x)$ where $f=\Delta_{\alpha\beta}$?

Comment: I am not commenting on what you need. The point of Hatcher's sentence is to explain why $d_2=0$; the rest of the sentence is using the commutators (etc.) to explain why $\Delta_{\alpha \beta}$ is homotopic to zero. Unstated but clear is the conclusion that $\deg (\Delta_{\alpha \beta})=0$ for all $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and therefore $d_2=0$.

Comment: In other words, when you say "I am trying to formally prove the following claim ..." and then you cite Hatcher, that is not an accurate citation, since Hatcher never makes that claim.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri Yes - agreed, thanks. I misinterpreted what he wrote. I'm just now trying to figure out why the statement, as it should be interpreted, is correct - namely, why $\Delta_{\alpha\beta}$ is homotopic to zero via the commutators (I'm not sure how to construct the homotopy $f_t$ when $\Delta_{\alpha\beta}$ is considered to be a map stated as a function of commutators). He makes this transition sound very obvious, yet it is not obvious to me.