# How to understand and formally define the homotopy between two maps when they are defined using commutators?

Tags: algebraic-topology

There are several locations in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology* where he defines attaching maps using commutators or words and then claims there's a homotopy between those maps (or, more precisely, maps that are derived from those maps) and other maps. The way he describes it, it sounds trivial, yet I'm unable to formalize it.

For example, in Example 2.37, he writes:

> The closed nonorientable surface $N_g$ of genus $g$ has a cell
> structure with one $0$ cell, $g$ $1$ cells, and one $2$ cell attached
> by the word $a^2_1a^2_2\dots a^2_g$. ... and $d_2 : \mathbb{Z} \to
>  \mathbb{Z}^g$ is specified by the equation $d_2(1) = (2, ··· , 2)$
> since each $a_i$ appears in the attaching word of the $2$ cell with
> total exponent $2$, which means that **each $\Delta_{\alpha\beta}$ is
> homotopic to the map $z\mapsto z^2$**, of degree $2$.

Similarly, in Example 2.36 he writes:

> ...$d_2$ is $0$ because each $a_i$ or $b_i$ appears with its inverse
> in $[a_1, b_1] \dots [a_g, b_g]$, **so the maps $\Delta_{\alpha\beta}$
> are homotopic to constant maps**.

Is this some kind of convention I'm not familiar with? How can I see these homotopies formally? Each of the homotopic maps is supposed to be from $S^1 \to S^1$, so is he viewing $S^1$ as a group that consists of the words generated by the faces we're attaching to the $1$-skeleton?

**Here is my attempt at starting to formalize this**, but still the homotopy is not clear:

We can view each map $\Delta_{\alpha\beta}: \partial D^2 = S^1 \to S^1$ as a map from the group of words generated by the faces of the boundary to the words generated by the corresponding loop in the $X^1$ skeleton to which we are attaching. So, for example, in the torus, the codomain can be the words generated by $a$, so $\{a, a^{-1}, e\}$ and the map will send the two horizontal faces to the empty word and the two vertical faces to $a$ and $-a$ correspondingly; the constant map will send all to the empty word. The homotopy between these two maps should now be defined how...? I'm familiar with a homotopy between functions from one space to another. Here we now have groups.

(Just to clarify - it is clear to me how the attaching maps work to define the $2$-skeleton. What is not clear to me is how these homotopies can be formally justified, and how these maps are defined from $S^1$ to $S^1$ when using commutators and words.)

There's a [related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1671399/understanding-example-2-36-in-hatchers-algebraic-topology-calculating-homology) that does not address this specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take the Klein bottle, $g=2,$ for simplicity. Then by definition Hatcher gives the bottle as the quotient of a figure eight $S^1\vee S^1$ and a disjoint disk $D^2$ via the map $\partial D^2\to S^1\vee S^1$ which is specified by the word $a_1^2a_2^2$ in $\pi_1(S^1\vee S^1)=\langle a_1,a_2\rangle.$ This is just an algebraic way of saying "wrap around the first circle twice and then the second circle twice", which is more useful for precision and will help in calculating the Klein bottle's fundamental group and homology once we want that.

As for $\Delta_{\alpha\beta},$ I don't remember Hatcher's exact notation but these are the two induced maps $\partial D^2\to S^1$ given by composing the attaching map with the map collapsing one or the other cirle of the figure eight. For instance, if we collapse the second circle, then the resulting $\Delta_{\alpha\beta}$ wraps twice around the remaining circle and then sits constant for the second half of the circumference of $\partial D^2.$ So the homotopy claim is simply that the two maps $S^1\to S^1,z\mapsto z^2,$ and $z\mapsto \left\{\begin{matrix} z^4, \mathrm{arg}(z)\le \pi\\ 1, \mathrm{else}\end{matrix}\right.$ are homotopic. If you know about $\pi_1(S^1)$ then you know that these maps *must* be homotopic because they both wind twice about the origin. Either way, you should be able to give an explicit homotopy between them if you want one.

Comment: I see - so basically, Hatcher is indeed using the fundamental group (which I am not really familiar with) when he's referring to the words and commutators, and then these on homotopy become more trivial (as implied by the way they are presented), correct? (i.e., there's no avoiding going through the fundamental group when attempting to understand this). (I'm asking because this whole chapter doesn't deal with the fundamental group directly at all, so it's somewhat surprising).

Comment: @Anon No, you probably don't really need the fundamental group to understand this. He's not saying anything meaningfully different than "Wrap around the first one twice, then the second one twice." On the other hand you are going to need to read Chapter 1 at some point if you're learning algebraic topology.

Comment: Thanks, still wondering though how to formally get this 'wrap around twice' thing to be homotopic to a constant function :) I guess for that I *would* need the fundamental group. In any case, I'll wait to see if there's any way to formally state the homotopy in the form of words/commutators and if not - I will accept your answer.

Comment: @Anon I don't really understand what you're asking for with the last sentence: the only possible interpretation that comes to mind is literally identical with doing a calculation in the fundamental group. 

But the map that's homotopic to a constant function is the map that wraps around once, then turns around and wraps in the opposite direction. It should again be straightforward to write down an explicit homotopy between that and a constant map.

Comment: So in the case of the Torus that I mentioned, my first map, $f_0$ is the map (for the $a$-loop) which is specified by $aa^{-1}$. The second map $f_1$ is a constant map, which can be specified as the empty word $=aa^{-1}$. Since the two are identical then we immediately obtain the homotopy (?); and in the Klein example, $f_0=a^2$ and $f_1=z^2$? This all feels a bit odd since these are not 'classic' maps between two spaces $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: @Anon No, these are ways of identifying perfectly ordinary maps of spaces. $aa^{-1}$ means "wrap around couterclockwise, then counterclockwise." Since $aa^{-1}=e$ in the fundamental group, general results on the fundamental group that you have not studied imply there is a homotopy between them. This is a continuous map of the circle that you can easily write down an explicit formula for (i.e. $z^2$ on the upper half plane and $z^{-2}$ on the lower), and then an explicit formula for its nullhomotopy.

Comment: The Klein bottle formulae you write down are confused. $a^2$ is an element of the fundamental group; $z^2$ is a formula for a map on the unit circle viewed as a subset of the complex plane.

Comment: Thanks! I now see that it's really a matter of translating between the two definitions of a map - one being specifying the map as a continuous map on the unit circle and the other as an element in the fundamental group. Since these two definitions are equivalent, there is no problem taking the map as an element in the fundamental group and representing it as a map for which a homotopy to another map can be defined.